# How to use xargs with find?

Tags: linux, bash, find, xargs

I have a large number of files on disk and trying to `xargs` with `find` to get faster output.
`find . -printf '%m %p\n'|sort -nr`

If I write `find . -printf '%m %p\n'|xargs -0 -P 0 sort -nr`, it gives error `argument line is too long`. Removing `-0` option gives other error.

Comment: The disk is the bottleneck, and all the parallel invocations will be competing for that shared resource. Parallelizing is probably not likely to help much.

Comment: You may have too many files concentrated in a small number of directories. Try to spread files across as many as directories as possible.

Comment: find ... -print | sort  is something else than find ... -print | xargs ... sort - are you sure you do understand what xargs is doing?

Comment: [BashFAQ/003 (How can I sort or compare files based on some metadata attribute (newest / oldest modification time, size, etc)?)](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) may be useful for you.

Comment: You can't use `xargs` to parallelize a sort.  At best you'll get a bunch of separate sorts of parts of the input that won't combine in any useful way.  GNU `sort` has a `--parallel` option.  That might help you.  There's potentially useful information about it in [Sort --parallel isn't parallelizing](https://superuser.com/q/938558/1081707).  There's also a reference to an alternative sorting tool called `parsort` that is designed for parallel sorting.

Comment: Parallelizing the sort won't help much if most of the time is being spent on traversing the file system.    I suggest you try running `time find . -printf '%m %p\n' >/dev/null`.  If the "real" time is nearly as long as the combined `find ... | sort ...` time then there's no point trying to optimize the sorting.  If `find` is taking a very long time, maybe you  could try using [fd](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) instead.  It's reputed to be significantly faster.  YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

- The parallelism commands such as `xargs` or `GNU parallel`
  are applicable *only if* the task can be divided into multiple independent
  jobs e.g. processing multiple files at once with the same command.
  It is not possible to use `sort` command with these parallelism commands.
- Although `sort` has `--parallel` option, it may not work well for
  piped input. (Not fully evaluated.)

As side notes:

- The mechanism of `xargs` is it reads items (filenames in most cases) from
  the standard input and generates individual commands by combining
  the argument list (command to be executed) with each item. Then you'll
  see the syntax `.. | xargs .. sort` is incorrect because each filename
  is passed to `sort` as an argument then `sort` tries to sort the *contents*
  of the file.
- The `-0` option to `xargs` tells xargs that input items are delimited
  by a null character instead of a newline. It is useful when the input
  filenames contain special characters including a newline character.
  In order to use this feature, you need to coherently handle the piped
  stream in that way: putting `-print0` option to `find` and `-z` option
  to `sort`. Otherwise the items are wrongly concatenated and will cause
  `argument line is too long` error.

Answer (score -1):

Suggesting to use `locate` command instead of `find` command.

You might want to update files database with `updatedb` command.

Read more about `locate` command [here](https://linuxhandbook.com/locate-command/).